# How to get the build creator

Tags: build, build-automation, tfsbuild

I would like to get in a build activity the build creator.

Is it possible to get them from the `CodeActivityContext`?

How can i do this?

Comment: Define what you mean by "build creator"?  The person who authored the build workflow, the person who created the build def, the person who queued this specific build, the person who the build is "on behalf of" for CI/gated Builds?

Comment: The name of the person, who queued this build in visual studio for execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get IBuildDetail object for build from context extensions (or pass it to activity as argument)

`context.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>()`

Properties from there will provide what you need

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail.aspx

Public property RequestedBy Gets the user who requested this build.

Public property RequestedFor    Gets the user for whom this build was requested.